# WAS Liberty not serving images, css, js

Tags: websphere-liberty

I have an application which is working fine on Websphere server (as war and Eclipse Project). 
**Direct deploy on Liberty through WAR is also working fine.**

I was trying to deploy it on WAS Liberty **through Eclipse project**. There are no console errors but once the application loads, none of the following files are getting loaded in the web page: js, gif, css

Because of this the page is looking distorted and most of the functionality is lost. 
Surprisingly there are some JSPs in the js folder and these are getting loaded, so looks like the folders are published properly. But for all the mentioned files (js etc), I get following error in the browser console: *500 (Internal Server Error)* . 
There are no errors and the server log is also clean.

My setup: WAS Liberty 8.5, RHEL 6.5. Eclipse Luna, WDT 8.5.5.2. Project having Eclipse structure, not maven. 
I have tried both loose config and 'from workspace' settings

Edit1:  I noticed that Spring beans are not getting initialized properly. Getting null pointer on applicationContext.getBean.

Comment: Liberty by default serves static files, so it should work. So check links to images in your html/jsp files. And try to access image directly by putting url in the browser. Also check messages.log file in the LIBERTY\usr\servers\serverName\logs folder.

Comment: Checked the logs, no useful error. If directly copy pasting the links on browser I get "null for uri:  <URI>"
And in browser console the same 500 error.

Comment: Does your project by chance have a maven structure? Or Eclipse structure?

Comment: Its having Eclipse Structure.

Comment: It's working fine for me on Win, so it probably is related to Eclipse on Linux. Did you check file permissions? Or tried to run Eclipse/Liberty as root user? You may try to post your issue on IBM forum - https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/?community=wasdev

Comment: Thanks I have posted my question on the wasdev community also. + I am setting the dev environment on windows machine, will update the results here once done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found the problem.

As I guessed this was related to spring initialization, though the problem was more code related.

Due to wrong implementation of REST implementation, where the base path was set as root application path (“/”), rest API classes were getting instantiated on application load and were then making calls to code which was instantiating few Spring beans. 
But at this point the Spring listeners had not fired, hence the appcontext was empty.  Some of the base application object were getting initialized with empty beans and hence spring security context and related classes were failing to serve the application content properly. (Problem is spring related code is created by another team and we just get the jar, hence I am not even able to debug it properly, so I don't know where it was failing exactly)

The thing that makes it Liberty specific is: The same problematic code is working fine on Websphere full profile and Weblogic and even on Liberty if we deploy as WAR. Not sure what classloading difference is causing difference in behaviour.

Thanks to all who took time and efforts for replying.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue using open liberty and Eclipse Krazo when the base path is

```
application path (“/”)
```

so i have changed the path as shown below

```
package io.openliberty.sample;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("")
public class ConfigApplication extends Application {
}
```

Now the CSS and imgs are loading with no issues.